# Python: nested for loop is interrupted by empty value in dictionary

Tags: python, api, append, nested-loops

I'm very new to loops and API's. I am currently trying out IEX's sandbox for gathering financial data. What I've done is gathered a list of stock symbols supported by IEX and am then using that list to call for data and append it to a pandas dataframe. The problem is that some years IEX does not have data for a specific security. I'd like to keep that security in the data frame and just write N/A if the values are missing. The code for my loop is as follows:

```
my_columns = ['date','Ticker','Price','o_cash_flow','total_income',
          'total_assets','total_liab','rev','ebit','ttm_eps',
          'shares_out','profit_margin','total_rev','2year_return',
          '1year_return','6month_return','3month_return','1month_return']

financials_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = my_columns)

for symbol_string in symbol_strings:
    batch_api_call_url = f'{sandbox_url}/stable/stock/market/batch?symbols={symbol_string}&types=price,financials,stats,advanced-stats&range=2q&token={token}'
    data = requests.get(batch_api_call_url).json()
    for symbol in symbol_string.split(','):
        print(data[symbol])
        financials_df = financials_df.append(
        pd.Series
     [
            data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['fiscalDate'],
            symbol,
            data[symbol]['price'],
            data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['cashFlow'],
            data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['netIncome'],
            data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['totalAssets'],
            data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['totalLiabilities'],
            data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['revenue'],
            data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['ebit'],
            data[symbol]['stats']['ttmEPS'],
            data[symbol]['stats']['sharesOutstanding'],
            data[symbol]['advanced-stats']['profitMargin'],
            data[symbol]['advanced-stats']['totalRevenue'],
            data[symbol]['stats']['year2ChangePercent'],
            data[symbol]['stats']['year1ChangePercent'],
            data[symbol]['stats']['month6ChangePercent'],
            data[symbol]['stats']['month3ChangePercent'],
            data[symbol]['stats']['month1ChangePercent']
    ],
        index = my_columns),
            ignore_index = True
        )
```

I then receive an error of "KeyError: 'financials'" This is because the 2nd call for financials is missing for some securities. I'd like the loop to just replace the data with N/A in the dataframe and continue calling data from the api when this occurs. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You're missing a `(` after `pd.Series`

Comment: You'll need to use `if` statements to check if `financials` is available.

Answer (score 0):

You have the use the `.get` method instead of the `[...]` syntax to retrieve values. This allows you to add a default value for the missing cases.
But since you built this with hardcoded dict queries, you have to cascade the `get`s for nested field retrievals, and this can become lenghty, if reliable.
Also, `.get` does not check for elements in a sequence: trying to retrieve the element at index 0 from an empty sequence would also error.

So, `data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['netIncome']` would have to to become

`(((d3 if (d3:=d2[0].get("netIncome")) else "N/A")if d2 else "N/A" )if (d2:=d1.get('financials') else "N/A") if (d1:=data[symbol].get('financials')) else "N/A"`

It can clearly be seen this is not feasible for even a medium structure like yours. The best thing to do is to build a helper function to retrieve the nested data from the "path" to the data, defaulting to a value, and call this function every time:

```
def retr(obj, path, default="N/A"):
   try:
      for index in path:
          obj = obj[index]
   except (IndexError, KeyError):
      return default
   return obj
```

And them use a call to `retr` to compose each of your data items:

`data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['cashFlow'],`

becomes:

`retr(data, ["symbol", "financials", "financials", 0 ,"cashFlow"]),`

Answer (score -1):

Check if `financials` is defined with an `if` statement.

```
if 'financials' in data[symbol]['financials']:
    row =  [
        data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['fiscalDate'],
        symbol,
        data[symbol]['price'],
        data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['cashFlow'],
        data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['netIncome'],
        data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['totalAssets'],
        data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['totalLiabilities'],
        data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['revenue'],
        data[symbol]['financials']['financials'][0]['ebit'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['ttmEPS'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['sharesOutstanding'],
        data[symbol]['advanced-stats']['profitMargin'],
        data[symbol]['advanced-stats']['totalRevenue'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['year2ChangePercent'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['year1ChangePercent'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['month6ChangePercent'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['month3ChangePercent'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['month1ChangePercent']
    ]
else:
    row = [
        'N/A',
        symbol,
        data[symbol]['price'],
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        'N/A',
        data[symbol]['stats']['ttmEPS'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['sharesOutstanding'],
        data[symbol]['advanced-stats']['profitMargin'],
        data[symbol]['advanced-stats']['totalRevenue'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['year2ChangePercent'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['year1ChangePercent'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['month6ChangePercent'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['month3ChangePercent'],
        data[symbol]['stats']['month1ChangePercent']
    ]
financials_df = financials_df.append(pd.Series(row, index=my_columns), ignore_index=True)
```